# Select max value and output its ID. Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection of flight data and am building a pipeline to filter for a specific result.  So far, my pipeline looks like this.  Questions below it

```
db.flights.aggregate([
{$project:{month:{$month:"$flight_date"},cancelled: "$cancelled"}}
,
{$group:{_id:"$month",total:{$sum:"$cancelled"},count:{$sum:1}}}
,
{$project:{_id:"$_id",ratio:{$divide: ["$total","$count"] } }}
,
{$sort:{ratio:-1}}
])
```

Which gives me the desired out put of:

```
{ "_id" : 2, "ratio" : 0.08839657282741738 }
{ "_id" : 1, "ratio" : 0.0695304467039872 }
{ "_id" : 3, "ratio" : 0.05533276450511945 }
{ "_id" : 6, "ratio" : 0.027439912192280983 }
{ "_id" : 7, "ratio" : 0.019906046890752697 }
{ "_id" : 5, "ratio" : 0.016912022432527166 }
{ "_id" : 4, "ratio" : 0.016336963769726605 }
{ "_id" : 8, "ratio" : 0.014001570269562941 }
{ "_id" : 12, "ratio" : 0.013169724213339814 }
{ "_id" : 11, "ratio" : 0.011361386138613861 }
{ "_id" : 9, "ratio" : 0.008534781659918047 }
{ "_id" : 10, "ratio" : 0.007929126168441613 }
```

Question: So far so good.  Now how do I add one pipeline operator which returns only the max ratio?  I've sorted for it but I would prefer to return one document containing just the ID of the max ratio, and the max ratio (rather than a collection of documents).

What command can be added to transform the above output to the below output, or something similar.  So far, my attempt at using max has been calculating the max of one number: calculating the max in each document, rather than than the max across all documents.  IE its determining the max horizontally rather than vertically.

```
{ "_id_max_ratio" : 2, "max_ratio" : 0.08839657282741738 }
```

Comment: just add {$limit: 1} at the end of your pipeline. Also note that your first $project is useless, you can merge it with the folowing $group like this : `{$group:{_id: {month:"$flight_date"}, cancelled: "$cancelled"}, count:{$sum:1}}`

Comment: Thanks man.  Ya sort and limit did the trick.  I kinda like not merging since I'm a newbie, so each step is only one step, much easier for me to visualize